# Javascript for going after maximum

Tags: javascript

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

`acc.length=4`
When I output variable `i` after for, the output is 0, 1, 2 and 3. But if I output `i` after `acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {` the output is 6 everytime.

Normaly variable `i` is going from 0 to 3. Why i have the ouput 6 after eventlistener?

Comment: is `i` global? do you have another `for` loops? where does the ouput takes place?

Comment: Needles is all the code

Comment: @LionSnow then add only parts that reuse `i` variable, provided code doesn't reproduce your issue. Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)